# Setting a multiselect attribute using the attribute code

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute

I am trying to create products programmatically. In the task, I need to set the multiselect attribute options. I tried like below, but it is not working.

```
$optionIds[] = $optionId; //$optionIds = array(41,42,43)
$product->setData($attributeCode, $optionIds);
```

But it is not working. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiselect values are saved id db as imploded string, so if you created your attribute correctly, imploding array should solve the problem.

Comment: May I know the table name?

Comment: catalog_product_entity_varchar

Answer (score 3):

The values from multiselect attributes are saved concatenated by comma 1,4,6 so you need to replace your code from

```
$optionIds[] = $optionId; //$optionIds = array(41,42,43)
$product->setData($attributeCode, $optionIds);
```

To

```
$optionIds = implode(',',$optionId); //$optionIds = array(41,42,43)
$product->setData($attributeCode, $optionIds);
```